# Is there a Python equivalent to MATLAB's vct2mtx?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a list of points (latitudes and longitudes) and a corresponding list of values for those points. Now I would like to make a 2D grid from this. While it is straight-forward to loop over sorted longitudes and latitudes to create the 2D grid, I was wondering if there is an efficient Python function (perhaps in numpy?)

```
import numpy as np
lats = [1,2,3] 
lons=[4,5,6] 
values=[7,8,9]

def vec2mtx(lats, lons, values):
    Z = np.zeros((len(set(lats)),len(set(lons))))
    Z.fill(-9999) # no data value
    lats_grid = np.zeros((len(set(lats)),len(set(lons))))
    lons_grid = np.zeros((len(set(lats)),len(set(lons))))
    search_sorted_lats = np.searchsorted(np.sort(list(set(lats))), lats)
    search_sorted_lons = np.searchsorted(np.sort(list(set(lons))), lons)
    Z[(search_sorted_lats, search_sorted_lons)] = values
    lats_grid[(search_sorted_lats, search_sorted_lons)] = lats
    lons_grid[(search_sorted_lats, search_sorted_lons)] = lons
    Z = np.flipud(Z)
    return lats_grid, lons_grid, Z

lats_grid, lons_grid, Z = vec2mtx(lats, lons, values)
```

[image: What Z looks like]

This code does what I need to do, but this seems like too many lines for something that should be like a one liner in numpy?

Comment: I don't know MatLab well at all, but the data structures involved appear to be quite different (Python, for instance, doesn't have a built-in point type, ignoring `complex` anyway.) Can you provide an exact example of what your Python lists look like?

Comment: well, it doesn't have to be a point type. For the sake of example. Say, lats = [1,2,3]; lons=[4,5,6], values=[7,8,9]

Comment: So far what I've found is this, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler way to do it. 
lats = np.searchsorted(np.sort(list(set(lat))), lat)
lons = np.searchsorted(np.sort(list(set(lon))), lon)
Z[(lats, lons)] = values

Comment: @chepner: my question exactly.  A list comprehension (or comprehension for another data structure) will likely solve the problem.

Comment: It's not obvious what the MATLAB function is doing - as best I can tell it is part of mapping toolbox, not basic MATLAB.  Put your example, with any iterative code, in the box of your question.  Code does not format well in comments.  It's easier to help if we know exactly what you expect.

Comment: I though MATLAB's vec2mtx was doing what I wanted,
 but it seems like it doesn't, sorry, if that was confusing. Anyway, now I believe the question is clear. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Looks like you need `np.unique` and to stop calling `set` on every other line.

Comment: Two calls to `unique`, with the inverse indices returned, one call to `meshgrid` and a fancy assignment like you already have should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet updated with recommendations from Mad Physicist. Perhaps someone else finds this useful:

```
import numpy as np
lats = [1,2,3] 
lons=[4,5,6] 
values=[7,8,9]

def vec2mtx(lats, lons, values):
    ''' Convert vectors of lat,lon locations and values to 2D grid'''
    Z = np.zeros((len(set(lats)),len(set(lons))))
    Z.fill(-9999) # no data value
    lat_set = np.unique(lats); lons_set = np.unique(lons)
    lats_grid = np.zeros((len(lats_set),len(lons_set)))
    lons_grid = np.zeros((len(lats_set),len(lons_set)))
    search_sorted_lats = np.searchsorted(np.sort(lats_set), lats)
    search_sorted_lons = np.searchsorted(np.sort(lons_set), lons)
    Z[(search_sorted_lats, search_sorted_lons)] = values
    lats_grid[(search_sorted_lats, search_sorted_lons)] = lats
    lons_grid[(search_sorted_lats, search_sorted_lons)] = lons
    Z = np.flipud(Z)
    return lats_grid, lons_grid, Z

lats_grid, lons_grid, Z = vec2mtx(lats, lons, values)
```